# How to use Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, popup

I found a reference to Leaflet in a interactive map shown in a page of the town of Berlin: https://www.berlin.de/landesdenkmalamt/denkmale/liste-karte-datenbank/denkmaldatenbank/denkmalkarte.php

Zooming into this map, one gets popups that show the name of a monument, which is also a link to a record in a database with a description of the monument.

This kind of map is exactly what I am thinking to realise, although in my project popup wouldn't point o monuments but to other kind of thinks.

Now: the Startguide and the Tutorial of Leaflet I see lines of code that one should insert somewhere: this is my newbie-newbie question: WHERE? In the html code of the page where the map should be shown? Or where else?

I'd be grateful if somebody would answer such a basic question. That would also allow me to understand if I'm equal to this task.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should very probably start with tutorials about basic website with JavaScript. Then the Leaflet tutorial should make sense to you. You can also use the Leaflet Plunker, it will give you a basic page with everything.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately without basic knowledge of js, html and css it will be hard to build such a website. I would like to start with the examples from the leaflet page. Some time ago I built a website with leaflet basics. If you are interested, take a look, it may help a little in the construction [leaflet-examples](https://tomik23.github.io/leaflet-examples/) but as I mentioned at the beginning, you need to have some knowledge of js.